# SQL joining three tables to result in two columns, based on a DATE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose I have three tables like this:

```
TABLE_X     TABLE_Y     TABLE_Z
---------------------------------------
2012/1/1    a           b
2012/1/2    a           b
...         a           b
2012/3/17   a           b
2012/3/18   a           b
2012/3/19   a           b
...         a           b
2012/12/22  a           b
2012/12/23  a           b
2012/12/24  a           b
...         a           b
2013/1/1    a           b
```

I need to do a view that uses GETDATE() as a condition.  All values on and in the past of GETDATE() will take on `TABLE_Y` cols.  All values in the future of GETDATE() will take on `TABLE_Z` cols.

```
view_TABLE_X_JOIN_Y_Z
---------------------
2012/1/1    a
2012/1/2    a
...         a
2012/3/17   a
2012/3/18   a
2012/3/19   a
...         a
2012/12/22  a
GETDATE()   a
2012/12/24  b
...         b
2013/1/1    b
2013/1/2    b
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT x.Date
    ,CASE WHEN GETDATE() > x.Date THEN z.Value
    ELSE y.Value
    END AS Value
FROM TABLE_X x
LEFT JOIN TABLE_Y y ON x.Date = y.Date
LEFT JOIN TABLE_Z z ON x.Date = z.Date
```

The problem is that dates are not perfect FK references. i.e.  Dates in TABLE_X is complete, but they are missing in some places in Y and Z.

Comment: So what seems to be the problem? Do you have a concrete question regarding something you have tried ?

Comment: @aviad I have edited the question for further clarifications.

Comment: And what do you want to do when a date is missing? Skip that line? Consider it 'long ago'? For what that matters: there are no duplicates?

Comment: I see. Full join is your friend as appears in confusion's answer

Comment: When it's missing, it should simply repeat the last non-null value.  Ex:  In X: 2012/1/1, 2012/1/2, 2012/1/3... In y: 2012/1/1/, [missing], 2012/1/3... Then on the [missing] date, take 2012/1/1's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN table_x.date_column > GETDATE() THEN table_y.some_column 
                                            ELSE table_z.some_column END
FROM table_x JOIN table_y JOIN table_z (insert appropriate join clauses)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of understanding your question correctly, but I think this would do it:

```
SELECT x.date, y.*
FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.date = y.date
WHERE x.date <= GETDATE()

UNION

SELECT x.date, z.*
FROM x INNER JOIN z ON x.date = z.date
WHERE x.date > GETDATE()
```

I assume that x, y and z are different tables and the dates in y and z are foreign keys referencing x, also y and z should have the same column structure

Comment: Ahh, thanks.  That's important; but the tables do not share the same structure so a UNION didn't work for me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure, try this,

```
create view view_TABLE_X_JOIN_Y_Z as(select y.* from table_y y
where getdate() > (select date from TABLE_X x where y.date=x.date)
union all
select z.* from table_z z where getdate() <= (select date from TABLE_x x 
where z.date=x.date))
```

Provided, both tables should have same column structure